# When i use tensorflow 2.8.0 to fine-tune bert meet this bug: hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess) 'CaseFoldUTF8'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model, tensorflow2.x

my code follows:

```
bert_model_name = 'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8'
map_name_to_handle = {'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8/1'}
map_model_to_preprocess = { 'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8':
        'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3'}
tfhub_handle_encoder = map_name_to_handle[bert_model_name]
tfhub_handle_preprocess = map_model_to_preprocess[bert_model_name]
print(f'BERT model selected           : {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
print(f'Preprocess model auto-selected: {tfhub_handle_preprocess}')

bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess) # here encounter bugs
```

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _get_op_def(self, type)
4176     if name:
-> 4177       if isinstance(name, compat.bytes_or_text_types):
4178         name = compat.as_str(name)

KeyError: 'CaseFoldUTF8'

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by tensorflow_text.
You need to import tensorflow_text as text in the top of your code. Like:

```
import os
import shutil
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow_text as text
```

If there's no tensorflow_text  in your environment,you need to install it. Use:

```
pip install -q -U "tensorflow-text==2.8.*"
```

Comment: Learn more about the problem, see: https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert?hl=en